# Use Google keyword corrections in program

Tags: java, spell-checking

Let's say I have a list of words that are not spelled correctly. I have a dictionary that corrects them but there may be some words not present in the dictionary. Is there a way for me to search those misspelled words in Google and retrieve the first "Did you mean:" suggestion made by Google.

Comment: Does Google allow you to use their data?

Comment: I am simply using their suggested corrections for words that I have provided. I am not sure if that would be called using Google's data.

Comment: I know a story about a Belgian guy which made an SmartPhone app that took information from the site of the National Company for Belgium Rails (or NMBS in Dutch) for making it possible to get a simple view of the train time tables on the small screen of the phone. A few weeks later, when NMBS knew that he made that app, the guy (an innocent student at highschool) had to pay a punish (I'm not sure of the word punish. But he had to pay the NMBS a lot of money). **So, be careful when you do such a things**

Comment: I guess so, but that means if you type in a search query into Google, you should not use the suggested correction returned by them, even if it is what you want. I'll send them an email anyways. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just do a search for those words in Google by going to the google.com URL + the string of words(I'm not sure of the exact Google search URL), have the search term process in the background, then use something like XPATH and [HTMLCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) to see if there is a "Did you mean" text present. If so, present it to the user.

But I think Google now does an auto-correction search, so you may see "Searching for: CORRECTED SPELLING", something you should also take into consideration.